# Find And Update in array of subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm I newbie in mongodb world, and I've already spent a lot of time trying to resolve the following problem.

My collection is called 'routes' with the documents:

```
{
    idGateway: 0,
    priority: 1,
    channels: [
        {
            id: 'chanel_1',
            control: {
                timestamp: ISODate("2015-09-19T16:17:12.393Z"),
                qty: 3
            }
        },
        {
            id: 'chanel_2',
            control: {
                timestamp: ISODate("2015-09-18T16:17:12.393Z"),
                qty: 5
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    idGateway: 1,
    priority: 2,
    channels: [
        {
            id: 'chanel_3',
            control: {
                timestamp: ISODate("2015-09-19T16:17:12.393Z"),
                qty: 3
            }
        },
        {
            id: 'chanel_4',
            control: {
                timestamp: ISODate("2015-09-18T16:17:12.393Z"),
                qty: 5
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My needs are select a document and at the same time update its timestamp/qty fields (as a FindAndModify). The criteria to selection is:

- Get the document with the lowest priority
- From the document, select the channels' document with the MAX(timestamp)
- Update timestamp and qty
- And return only the channels' document (channel_1).

So, once I've selected the channel_1 I have to avoid that other process select it again befor the update. How can I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "select the channels' document with the MAX(timestamp)"? And what are you updating the timestamp and quantity to?

Comment: With more detail, from the lowest 'priority' I have to select the older channel from the channels array.

Comment: And if (current_time + 1min > timestamp) set timestamp = current_time

Comment: For qty I have just to increment 1